# How to have two css animations in one tag

Tags: html, css, animation, web

I am working with css animations and I have a series of animations with different css tags. I start at #water then go to other animations then I want to go back to #water with a different animation. This is my code:

```
#water {
    position: relative;
    left: 48px;   
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 197px;
    -webkit-animation: squeez 2s 1s 1 forwards;
    -moz-animation: squeez 2s 1s 1 forwards;
    -o-animation: squeez 2s 1s 1 forwards;
    -webkit-animation: fadeOut 10s 10s 1 forwards;
    -moz-animation: fadeOut 10s 10s 1 forwards;
    -o-animation: fadeOut 10s 10s 1 forwards;
}
```

It does not work how I want it to. The code is disregarding the first animation "squeez" and only doing the animation "fadeOut" which messes everything up. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can comma-separate your animations, so you could do:

```
-webkit-animation: squeez 2s 1s 1 forwards, fadeOut 10s 10s 1 forwards;
-moz-animation: squeez 2s 1s 1 forwards, fadeOut 10s 10s 1 forwards;
-o-animation: squeez 2s 1s 1 forwards, fadeOut 10s 10s 1 forwards;
animation: squeez 2s 1s 1 forwards, fadeOut 10s 10s 1 forwards;
```

```css
div {
  -webkit-animation: squeez 2s 1s forwards, fadeOut 10s 5s forwards;
  animation: squeez 2s 1s forwards, fadeOut 10s 5s forwards;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #F00;
}
@-webkit-keyframes squeez {
  from {
    width: 100px;
  }
  to {
    width: 20px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
@keyframes squeez {
  from {
    width: 100px;
  }
  to {
    width: 20px;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the native CSS animation property, it should always be added after any prefixes. It also extends supports to IE 10 +. [Currently there is no reason to use any prefix other than `-webkit-`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

Comment: @misterManSam thanks for that, I'm typing on my iPhone at the minute and was at the time of answering this question, so didn't want to spend too long writing code, just wanted to get my point across. ;-)

Comment: No worries, being on mobile is a pain :) I also added a working snippet for kicks.